# Install Apps from the AppStore the automatic way

Tags: automation, app-store

I'm trying to write a script which makes it possible to download Apps from Apples AppStore the automatic way (on an jailbreaked device). So I can tell the script the names (or IDs) of the Apps (via JSON e.g.) and the script begins to download and install by its self.

Has anybody an idea how to implement such stuff?

Comment: Is your question related to Apple's app store? Please tag it accordingly to specify your question more precisely.